# How to pass a JSON array to a javascript function inside a string in php

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am working on an invoicing system and the controller in my mvc framework, for now, uses strings enclosed in single quotes. I am new to javascript but I couldn't avoid it. I have function that works and validates in a window.onload declaration but the same declaration inside the form creates an error. The html output is:

```
onclick="verifyAccount('{"1":null,"2":null,"3":null,"4":null,"5":null,"8":null,"9":null,"10":null,"21":null,"22":null}');" >
```

all the values are null because none have been created. in Firebug I get the error "
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal". I don't know what is needed to solve this. The line that causes the error is:

```
    <input type="radio" name="account" id="account" onclick="verifyAccount(\''.$accounts.'\');" >

    $form = '
    <script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("addLabor").onclick = function(){ addLabor("labor"); }
    document.getElementById("addPart").onclick = function(){ addPart("parts"); }
    document.getElementById("addAdjustment").onclick = function(){ addAdjustment("adjustments"); }
    document.getElementById("customer_id").onchange = function() { verifyAccount(\''.$accounts.'\'); }
    addLabor("labor");

    }

    </script>
$form = '
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("addLabor").onclick = function(){ addLabor("labor"); }
    document.getElementById("addPart").onclick = function(){ addPart("parts"); }
    document.getElementById("addAdjustment").onclick = function(){ addAdjustment("adjustments"); }
    document.getElementById("customer_id").onchange = function() { verifyAccount(\''.$accounts.'\'); }
    addLabor("labor");

    }

    </script>

    <form method="POST" class="formTable" id="addInvoice" action="/invoices/save"
onsubmit="return(validate());">
        <table class="buttons" >
            <tr>
            <td><input type="button" id="addLabor" value="Add labor"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="addPart" value="Add part"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="addAdjustment" value="Adjust"/></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="invoiceTable">
        <tr>
            <td><label>Date:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="date" name="date" maxlength="10" size="4" />
                <a href="javascript:NewCal(\'date\',\'MMDDYYYY\')">
                <img src="/images/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Pick a date"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Use Account?:</label></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="account" id="account" onclick="verifyAccount(\''.$accounts.'\')" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Work Order Number:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="number" id="number" maxlength="8" size="6" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Customer:</label></td>
            <td><select name="customer_id" id="customer_id" >'.$select.'</select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Job Name:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="job_name" id="job_name" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="labor"></table>
    <table id="parts"></table>
    <table id="adjustments"></table>
    <table id="payment"></table>

    </form>';
        $this->component($form);
     <form method="POST" class="formTable" id="addInvoice" action="/invoices/save"
onsubmit="return(validate());">
    <table class="buttons" >
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" id="addLabor" value="Add labor"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="addPart" value="Add part"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="addAdjustment" value="Adjust"/></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="invoiceTable">
        <tr>
            <td><label>Date:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="date" name="date" maxlength="10" size="4" />
                <a href="javascript:NewCal(\'date\',\'MMDDYYYY\')">
                <img src="/images/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Pick a date"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Use Account?:</label></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="account" id="account" onclick="verifyAccount(\''.$accounts.'\')" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Work Order Number:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="number" id="number" maxlength="8" size="6" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Customer:</label></td>
            <td><select name="customer_id" id="customer_id" >'.$select.'</select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Job Name:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="job_name" id="job_name" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="labor"></table>
    <table id="parts"></table>
    <table id="adjustments"></table>
    <table id="payment"></table>


</form>';
        $this->component($form);
```

Comment: Get rid of the single quotes. That should not be too difficult.
`verifyAccount({"1":null,"2":null,"3":null,"4":null,"5":null,"8":null,"9":null,"10":null,"21":null,"22":null});" >` will be valid

Comment: It's inside a single quoted string. Thats why the combination of single quotes and escaped single quotes exist.

Comment: One has to ask why you'd need to run a Javascript function on fixed data produced by PHP. Why not do the job in PHP and simply post the result into your HTML?

Comment: @MikeW, Good idea! What procedure would you recommend?

Comment: Pleas show the PHP that produces the input field

Comment: @CoreyRay I have no idea. I don't know what your functions do. That should be the subject of a different question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem are all the double-quotes, which keep starting and ending strings. This results in the `onclick` value being just:

```
onclick="verifyAccount('{"
```

With the rest being at best additional attributes or just junk.

The double-quotes that are part of the value need to be escaped/encoded, which can be done with [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities):

```
'... onclick="verifyAccount(\''.htmlentities($accounts).'\');" ...'
```

---

Though, another option is to take advantage of JSON's relation to JavaScript, outputting the string of JSON so that it's treated as a [JavaScript `Object` literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals):

```
'... onclick=\'verifyAccount('.$accounts.');\' ...'
```

Or, if `$results` still needs to be encoded as JSON:

```
'... onclick=\'verifyAccount('.json_encode($accounts).');\' ...'
```

Resulting in:

```
<... onclick='verifyAccount({"1":null,"2":null",...})'>
```

The dependency of this is that `verifyAccount` would need to be adjusted to expect an `Object` rather than a `String`.

Comment: This may break if content of json_encode has a single quote, such as in `"text":"it's my text"`

Comment: Just added an answer to deal with this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my suggestion

javaScript:

```
var account = <?php echo json_encode($accounts)?>;
```

or if you for some reason cannot get rid of the single qutotes:

```
 var account = JSON.parse('{"1":null,"2":null,"3":null,"4":null,"5":null,"8":null,"9":null,"10":null,"21":null,"22":null}');
```

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="account" id="account" onclick="verifyAccount(account)" />
```

or with less change:

```
echo '<input  ... onclick=\'verifyAccount('.json_encode($accounts).');\' >';
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're just missing the concatenation operators here.

So:

```
<input type="radio" name="account" id="account" onclick="verifyAccount(\''.$accounts.'\');" >
```

Becomes:

```
<input type="radio" name="account" id="account" onclick="verifyAccount('\'' + '.$accounts.' + '\'');" >
```

And you can correct me here, but I believe that is a PHP variable you're trying to insert there, so it really should become:

```
<input type="radio" name="account" id="account" onclick="verifyAccount('\'' + '.<?php echo $accounts ?>.' + '\'');" >
```

Comment: Don't you mean `echo '<input type="radio" name="account" id="account" onclick=\'verifyAccount('.json_encode($accounts).');\' >'`

Comment: I was assuming the html was outside of PHP tags by design. However, @mplungjan your solution would be MUCH cleaner.

Comment: It would be much cleaner but I am learning this as I go and didn't really plan much. I know it's a deviance on my part but I'm not a javascript expert by far. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

To prevent both single quotes (`'`) and double quotes (`"`) to break your `onclick` encapsulation, you need to get rid of one of the two. As I have a preference for double quotes in attributes, and considering that `json_encode` returns double quotes, here's what I do:

```
echo '<input type="radio" name="account" id="account" onclick="verifyAccount('.htmlspecialchars(json_encode($accounts)).');"/>';
```

For example, the following object will work as expected:

```
array('user1' => 'Username is \'quit3" strange and \\ problematic!');
```

Which will be exported by PHP to:

```
{&quot;user1&quot;:&quot;Username is 'quit3\&quot; strange and \\ problematic!&quot;}
```

So it ends on:

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="account" id="account" onclick="var user ={&quot;user1&quot;:&quot;Username is 'quit3\&quot; strange and \\ problematic!&quot;}; console.log(user.user1);"/> Click me!</label>
```