# Pass list from an onclick to jquery method

Tags: html, jquery, onclick

I am trying to pass a c# list parameter using an onclick to a jquery method. It refuses to go to the method I am assuming its the  brackets [] that causes that and the string inside the list have slashes & other characters. A string inside the list might look like this; "*abc/def-"

Please assist

```
<input type="radio" class="btn-check" value="Maybe" name="ckhanswerA" id="chk" onclick="nextSlide(@Json.Serialize(@question))" />

function nextSlide(question) {
    debugger;
    var myList = JSON.parse(question);

}
```

Comment: Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: BTW TRY : `onclick="nextSlide('@Json.Serialize(@question)')"`

Comment: *the string inside the list* - as noted above, the problem is that you *don't* have a string in your onclick, you have an object, which makes no sense for HTML (which must be a string).   Always check the *rendered* HTML, you'll see that the rendered HTML is not valid *for HTML*.  Add quotes as above.

Comment: @Anant-Alivetodie with the quotes i "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

Comment: could you please share the value of `@Json.Serialize(@question)`? if it's big then initial part of it otherwise whole of it. Update it in your question.

Comment: @Anant-Alivetodie this how the html looks <input type="radio" class="btn-check" value="Maybe" name="ckhanswerA_3" id="chk_a9682c99-bf0c-4c90-93db-416ad5f06a96" onclick="nextSlide1('[{" personaquestionapipathid":4,"apipath":"isstudent="" ","returntype":"bool","flagactive":true},{"personaquestionapipathid":5,"apipath":"islocal="" ","returntype":"bool","flagactive":true}]')"="">

Comment: this is PHP solution but you can get the idea how to do it (in c#) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17636615/4248328

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the generated JSON so that it can be used in the string variable.

```
<input type="radio" class="btn-check" value="Maybe" name="ckhanswerA" id="chk" onclick='nextSlide(@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Json.Serialize(@question)))' />
```

reference: [How to escape JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242118/how-to-escape-json-string)